# Anti-constraint on C# generics

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

Inspired by [Phil Haack's attempt on null or empty coalescing](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/06/16/null-or-empty-coalescing.aspx), I'm trying to write a couple of extension methods for the `string` object, as well as on the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, to simplify null or emtpy ckecking. However, I'm running into problems: when I'm attempting to call the `string` version of `AsNullIsEmpty`, the compiler treats my string as an `IEnumerable<char>`, and of course gives the wrong return type.

Is there any way to put an "anti-constraint" on the definition of the `IEnumerable` version, so that I can tell the compiler to use that one whenever the type of `T` is *not* `string`? Something like

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsNullIfEmpty(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    where T !: string
```

I know that I could just change the name of one of them, but I want to have the same name for consistency.

**Update:** It turns out my problem with the extension methods was solved another way, by fixing a simple and stupid error (I was using `str.IsNullOrEmpty()`, the extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, instead of `string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)`...) but since the question of anti-constraints on generics is still an interesting one, I won't delete it.

Comment: The compiler Will take the most specific available method. If you implement one string and makes sure it's available at the Call site you Will have no problem like the one described

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to create an overload of this extension that accepts a `string` as its `this` parameter.

```
public static string AsNullIfEmpty(this string value)
```

Doing this will cause the specifically-typed version to be considered a better overload match than the generic version.

As to your specific question ("Can I specify an 'anti-constraint' on a generic type parameter?"), the answer is no. You could get very close, though, with the `Obsolete` attribute.

```
[Obsolete("AsNullIfEmpty is not supported for strings.", true)]
public static string AsNullIfEmpty(this string value)
```

This would cause the compiler to report an error for this overload.

Comment: That's what I had - and as you see in my update, the extension method problem is solved. (The problem existed because of another error...). However, is there any way to specify anti-constraints?

Comment: Then when T is string, you get nice intellisense of 2 methods with identical signatures.

Comment: @Tomas: There's a simple answer to that one: No, there's no way to specify anti-constraints.

Comment: @Tomas: See my edit. The strict answer is "no", but the end result *is* possible.